# Doing BigDecimal accounting with Ruby. When can I convert to float?

Tags: ruby, floating-point

I basically want to know the best to convert my BigDecimal numbers to readable format (float perhaps) for the purposes of displaying them to the client:

In order to figure out liabilities, I do contributions - distributions from each address.

For example, if a person contributes 2 units to an address and that same address distributes 1 unit back to the person, then there is still a 1 unit liability. that's what's going on below. These numbers are all units of cryptocurrency.

Here's another example:

Say `address1` and `address2` contribute 2 coins each to `address3`, and `address3` distributes 1.0 coins to `address1` and 0.5 coins to `address2`, then `address3` has a 1.0 coin liability to `address1` and a 1.5 coin liability to `address2`.

So the actual data using BigDecimal below:

```
contributions = 
{"1444"=>#<BigDecimal:7f915c08f030,'0.502569E2',18(36)>,
"alice"=>#<BigDecimal:7f915c084018,'0.211E1',18(27)>,
 "address1"=>#<BigDecimal:7f915c0a4430,'0.87161E1',18(36)>,
 "address2"=>#<BigDecimal:7f915c0943f0,'0.84811E1',18(36)>,
 "address3"=>#<BigDecimal:7f915c0a43e0,'0.385E0',9(18)>,
 "address6"=>#<BigDecimal:7f915c09ebe8,'0.1E1',9(18)>,
 "address7"=>#<BigDecimal:7f915c09eb98,'0.1E1',9(18)>,
 "address8"=>#<BigDecimal:7f915c09d428,'0.15E1',18(18)>,
 "address9"=>#<BigDecimal:7f915c09d3d8,'0.15E1',18(18)>,
 "address10"=>#<BigDecimal:7f915c0a7540,'0.132E1',18(36)>,
 "address11"=>#<BigDecimal:7f915c0af8a8,'0.392E1',18(36)>,
 "address12"=>#<BigDecimal:7f915c0a4980,'0.14E1',18(36)>,
 "address13"=>#<BigDecimal:7f915c0af858,'0.2133333333 3333333333 33333334E1',36(54)>,
 "address14"=>#<BigDecimal:7f915c0a54c0,'0.3533333333 3333333333 33333334E1',36(45)>,
 "address15"=>#<BigDecimal:7f915c0a66e0,'0.1533333333 3333333333 33333334E1',36(36)>,
 "sdfds"=>#<BigDecimal:7f915c0a6118,'0.1E0',9(27)>,
 "sf"=>#<BigDecimal:7f915c0a6028,'0.1E0',9(27)>,
 "address20"=>#<BigDecimal:7f915c0ae688,'0.3E0',9(18)>,
 "address21"=>#<BigDecimal:7f915c0ae638,'0.3E0',9(18)>,
 "address23"=>#<BigDecimal:7f915c0ae070,'0.1E0',9(27)>,
 "address22"=>#<BigDecimal:7f915c0adf80,'0.1E0',9(27)>,
 "add1"=>#<BigDecimal:7f915c0ad328,'0.1E0',9(18)>,
 "add2"=>#<BigDecimal:7f915c0ad2d8,'0.1E0',9(18)>,
 "addx"=>#<BigDecimal:7f915c0acd10,'0.1E0',9(27)>,
 "addy"=>#<BigDecimal:7f915c0acc20,'0.1E0',9(27)>}
```

and the distributions:

```
distributions = 
 {"1444"=>#<BigDecimal:7f915a9068f0,'0.502569E2',18(63)>,
 "alice"=>#<BigDecimal:7f915a8f44e8,'0.211E1',18(27)>,
 "address1"=>#<BigDecimal:7f915a906800,'0.87161E1',18(54)>,
 "address2"=>#<BigDecimal:7f915a906710,'0.84811E1',18(54)>,
 "address3"=>#<BigDecimal:7f915a906620,'0.385E0',9(36)>,
 "address6"=>#<BigDecimal:7f915a8fdea8,'0.1E1',9(27)>,
 "address7"=>#<BigDecimal:7f915a8fddb8,'0.1E1',9(27)>,
 "address8"=>#<BigDecimal:7f915a8fd5e8,'0.15E1',18(18)>,
 "address9"=>#<BigDecimal:7f915a8fd4f8,'0.15E1',18(18)>,
 "address10"=>#<BigDecimal:7f915a8fc9b8,'0.132E1',18(36)>,
 "address11"=>#<BigDecimal:7f915a9071b0,'0.3920000000 0000003E1',27(45)>,
 "address12"=>#<BigDecimal:7f915a907660,'0.1400000000 0000001E1',27(36)>,
 "address13"=>#<BigDecimal:7f915a9070c0,'0.2133333333 3333337E1',27(45)>,
 "address14"=>#<BigDecimal:7f915a906530,'0.3533333333 3333333333 33333334E1',36(54)>,
 "address15"=>#<BigDecimal:7f915a8fc148,'0.1533333333 3333334E1',27(27)>,
 "sdfds"=>#<BigDecimal:7f915a907f98,'0.1E0',9(27)>,
 "sf"=>#<BigDecimal:7f915a907e08,'0.1E0',9(27)>,
 "address20"=>#<BigDecimal:7f915a906ad0,'0.3000000000 0000003E0',18(27)>,
 "address21"=>#<BigDecimal:7f915a9069e0,'0.3000000000 0000003E0',18(27)>,
 "address23"=>#<BigDecimal:7f915a9063c8,'0.1E0',9(27)>,
 "address22"=>#<BigDecimal:7f915a906238,'0.1E0',9(27)>,
 "add1"=>#<BigDecimal:7f915a9060a8,'0.5E-1',9(27)>,
 "add2"=>#<BigDecimal:7f915a905f18,'0.1E0',9(27)>}
```

Ideally, I want my liabilities to look like this:

```
{"add1"=>0.05,
"addx"=>0.1>,
"addy"=>0.1>}
```

But they look like this:

```
{"1444"=>0.0,
 "alice"=>0.0,
 "address1"=>0.0,
 "address2"=>0.0,
 "address3"=>0.0,
 "address6"=>0.0,
 "address7"=>0.0,
 "address8"=>0.0,
 "address9"=>0.0,
 "address10"=>0.0,
 "address11"=>-3.0e-16,
 "address12"=>-1.0e-16,
 "address13"=>-3.66666666666e-16,
 "address14"=>0.0,
 "address15"=>-6.6666666666e-17,
 "sdfds"=>0.0,
 "sf"=>0.0,
 "address20"=>-3.0e-17,
 "address21"=>-3.0e-17,
 "address23"=>0.0,
 "address22"=>0.0,
 "add1"=>0.05,
 "add2"=>0.0,
 "addx"=>#<BigDecimal:7f915c0acd10,'0.1E0',9(27)>,
 "addy"=>#<BigDecimal:7f915c0acc20,'0.1E0',9(27)>}
```

I don't want to include `-3.66666666666e-16` because that's essentially 0 and even Ruby accounts for it this way when you run `-3.66666666666e-16 > 0`... it returns `false`.

This is what I have... is the a better way? The code below is calculating the liabilities by subtracting `con` from `dis` and only selecting the liabilities that are greater than 0.0...that makes sense to me and it excludes 1-time grants of coins (there must be a matching contribution to be a liability). Then, I convert everything to floats so it's readable. Does this look right?

```
liab = @contributions.merge(@distributions) do |key, con, dis|
      (con - dis)
    end.select { |addr, amount| amount > 0.0 && @contributions.keys.include?(addr) }

    liab.merge(liab) do |k, old, new|
      k = new.to_f
    end
```

I want the amount returned in float format, not the big decimal object. Is what I'm doing okay? Will I keep accuracy if I convert to float at the end?

Comment: You can use [`round`](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.5.0/Float.html#method-i-round) to make the numbers more readable, or you can use string formatting, but keep in mind rounded numbers should be considered *approximate* and not exact. Floats are nothing but trouble when dealing with monetary units.

Comment: That odd value you're getting is equal to -0.00000000000000036667 which is ever so slightly below zero. Welcome to the wild, wonderful world of [floating point math](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E19957-01/806-3568/ncg_goldberg.html).

Comment: Yes, but `-3.66666666666e-16 < 0` will return `true`. (You are using `>` where you mean to use `<`).

Comment: @Jwan622 more explanation on what liability/distribution/addresses are would be very helpful in understanding the overall context

Comment: edited for you @BKSpurgeon

Comment: why not something like this to do the displaying only: `bigDecimalVariable.to_s(“+3F”).truncate(3)`

Comment: (you will lose accuracy if converting to floating format for displaying)